# Android wear and Android TV in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

What's the function Android TV and Android Wear in Android SDK manager in Android studio. Do I need to install these for all Api

Answer (score 0):

Those two components provide you a way to develop for Wear and TV apps, respectively. **If you only want to develop a phone app, you are not needed to install those.**

You can see more about the Android Wear SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) and Android TV SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html).

Comment: I need an app for min KitKat and Max marshmallow what should  I need to install

Comment: KitKat is API 19 and Marshmallow is API 23… So thos two are all you'd need to install.

Comment: @DIVIKARORA, Download Marshmallow. That's all! Ridsatrio is completely wrong about needing to download KitKat. You'll just need to mention API Level 19 as your minSdk, but that doesn't mean that you need to download it.

Comment: Ah my bad, I wasn't aware that you are only needed to consider `targetSdkVersion` in order to determine which to download. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android TV is for Android TV. If you don't need your app to run on an Android TV (which has a tiny marketshare anyway), then don't worry about it.

The same goes for Android Wear. If you don't need your app to run on an Android watch (which has a tiny marketshare anyway), then don't worry about it.

Also, you seem to misunderstand how Android versioning works. If you want to develop on a phone or a tablet, just download the latest version, you do not need to download the previous versions (except may be for one compatibility library that you might need).

In other words, if you're just a beginner, download as little as you can. Most beginners download almost everything and that's just a waste of space.

Comment: To add to your answer, if you are indeed a beginner and just want to try out things, just download the latest (non-preview) version of the SDK available. For now it means API 23 (Marshmallow). But do check because in most cases Android Studio already have it bundled together when you install it.

Comment: Earlier I was using eclipse ..now I am facing processing speed issues in studio..what should I do in order to Inc processing speed.I have 4 GB RAM in lappy

Comment: @DIVIKARORA, That's a different question, but I believe that question has already been asked and answered before on StackOverflow, so you just need to find it to find the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Provide me the link..I have asked other ques bcoz earlier was resolved